# I can't figure it out why the result of recursive call is different from iterative way.(MIPS code)

Tags: recursion, sum, iteration, mips

I am beginner about MIPS.
I have to make a MIPS code that has several conditons.

1. Get a positive integer n from the console
2. Calculate the sum from 1 to n both iteratively(which is using loop) and recursively(which is using recursive call)
3. And then print out the results on the console.
4. I have to wrtie them on one code.

So,  I  wordked on this code and this code provides wrong reslut on recursive call.
The result of the iterative way and recursive way must be same but it isn't.

I found some issues on this code. <move $a0, $s0 jal calculate_sum> I think I have to write them $a0, $t0 but whenever i wrote this. Result of recursive call isn't print out on the console.

This is my code.

```
.data
    integer:    .asciiz "\nEnter a positive integer: "
    result_1:   .asciiz "(Iterative)Sum from 1 to n: "
    result_2:   .asciiz "\n(Recursive)Sum from 1 to n: "
    newline:    .asciiz "\n"

.text
    main:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, integer
        syscall

        read_input:
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t0, $v0  

            # Calculate the sum iteratively
            li $t1, 0   # Initialize sum to 0
            li $t2, 1   # Initialize the counter to 1

            loop_iterative:
                add $t1, $t1, $t2   # Add counter to sum
                addi $t2, $t2, 1     # Increment the counter

                # Check if the counter is less than or equal to n
                ble $t2, $t0, loop_iterative
                
            
            #Call the recursive function to calculate the sum 
            move $a0, $s0
            jal calculate_sum       
            
            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall
                    
            # Print the result_1
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_1
            syscall

            move $a0, $t1
            li $v0, 1
            syscall
            
            # Print the result_2
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_2
            syscall

            move $a0, $v0
            li $v0, 1
            syscall

            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall

            # Exit the program
            li $v0, 10
            syscall
            
    calculate_sum:
        #Recursive function to calculate the sum
        #Input: $a0-n
        #Output: $v0-sum
        
        #if n<=1, return 1
        blez $a0, calculate_sum_base
        li $v0,0
        
    calculate_sum_loop:
        add $v0, $v0, $a0
        addi $a0, $a0, -1
        blez $a0, calculate_sum_end
        jal calculate_sum_loop
        
    calculate_sum_base:
            li $v0, 1
            
        calculate_sum_end:
            jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `$v0` against the calling convention.

That is the register for return values, yet you're expecting it to survive the recursive call — it won't.

You need to do one of the following:

- Do the addition after the recursive call, saving the original $a0, since that'll be wiped out by the call.
- Use/invent a non standard calling convention that doesn't reset the answer at each level of recursion.

Suggest going back to the C/high level language version of the recursive approach and try to copy that most exactly.  Probably the best approach to learning what you're supposed to from this exercise.  Though not shown suspect will be like the first alternative.